# How can I prevent the cursor from jumping when I close parentheses in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, customization

Is there a way to change Emacs' behavior when closing parentheses/bracket?

Right now, the cursor will jump to the opening bracket for a few seconds and will jump back after a while or when I start typing. I find this jumping back and forth really annoying.

Is there a way, to either

- change the color/shape of the cursor when it's just marking the opening bracket, or
- prevent the jumping at all, and just change the color of the matching pair?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try putting

```
(show-paren-mode 1)
(setq blink-matching-delay 0.3)
```

in your `.emacs`  or `.emacs.d/init.el`.

This prevents the jumping and highlights the matching pair.